# How to decode encrypted ssl packets in Go?

Tags: ssl, go, packet-sniffers

we are building a packet sniffer in go using gopacket, now the issue is for ssl traffic I am trying to decode the data, I have the key and certificate on the server but online i can find only partial answers, I am trying to use the x509 in the crypt package and the openssl package from spacemonkey, with not much success, any tutorial or suggestion I can look at ? I think i miss some bits on how to manipulate the private key and certificates

Thank you

Comment: What is the ciphersuite being negotiated? The preferred keyexchange algorithms are now ECDHE, which you can't decrypt without the pre-master secret. The point of forward secrecy is so that the stream _can't_ be decrypted later.

Comment: i see, we have AES_128_GCM with ECDHE_RSA, I thought if the webserver can decrypt the data with key and certificate on the same machine we would be able to do that as well ? wouldn't the pre-master secret being exchanged as well so we could grab it and decrypt it? thank you

Comment: wireshark can do it on the client side https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/

Comment: The secret is shared via a DH exchange, so it doesn't go over the wire. You need access to the client, and the wireshark example there uses session key logging, which I'm pretty sure is a feature only in nss, and really only used in firefox.

Comment: yes sorry wrong example, so i am trying to do it in the server , I did it a bit more digging and as I understand the DH exchange the server would receive the client public key encrypted, which then it combines with his private key to have the shared secret. and because I am trying to decrypt only incoming packets not the full http conversation, if i sniff the key exchange wouldn't i be able to get decryptable data from there to decrypt the rest of the packets ? thanks for the hints

Comment: In ECDHE_RSA, the keys are only used for signing the exchange, the ephemeral keys never go over the wire. Decrypting the traffic even when you do have the key data is still not trivial. I would start with seeing how wireshark handles your traffic, as it probably has the best support right now for recording and decrypting tls streams.

Comment: yes we could capture the client public key and build the ephemeral from there on the server probably but is much more complex then i thought also because stream needs to be reassembled in correct order, and for each connection keep track of these details is a huge task, thanks a lot

Comment: I happened to have a similar problem, did you solve it?

Comment: Hi @AshvinSharma no at the end even having all the certificates I didn't manage can't remember now if was just not possible or we got stuck on something, we let nginx handle the ssl and we analyse the packets after that